# ¿Cómo asigno variables de SI o NO a las condicionales if y else?

Tags: python, condiciones, else

Estoy intentando crear un algoritmo que de registre respuestas conforme se coloque `si` o `no`, y que dichas respuestas lleven a otras preguntas, pero al parecer, las únicas condiciones que funcionan son las numéricas Ejem:

```python
edad = int(input("¿Cuántos años tiene? "))
if edad < 18:
    print("Es usted menor de edad.")
else:
    print("Es usted mayor de edad.")
```

Quisiera saber como podría hacer que para que `if` y `else` redireccionen a un `print` o incluso a otro `if/else`, determinándose por escribir "si" o "no"

Comment: El código debe ir en texto, no en imagen. Por otro lado, así como está solo va a funcionar con enteros porque tienes un `int(...)` que envuelve a la instrucción `input()` e intentará convertir a número todo lo que metas por teclado. Si quitas ese `int()`, funcionará para cualquier cadena de caracteres.

Comment: Gracias pero ya lo intente, el problema es que sin importar los caracteres que coloque, da siempre el primer resultado, mi problema es que quisiera que redireccione a partir de escribir solo "si" o "no"

Comment: input("¿Ud. aun va a la escuela?")
if input:
    print("si es que responde si")
else:
    print("si es que responde no")

Comment: por lo que entiendo, queres que el usuario inserte la respuesta si o no (con un input?) si fuese asi.. (te lo voy a explicar, en palabras) si fuese asi.. yo haria un condicional que tome la respuesta del input y depende cual sea el String (si o no) seguiria mi codigo, y colocaria otro condicional mas, por si colocan otra respuesta, diferente a las anteriores, espero te sirva.. vas por buen camino.

Answer (score 0):

El problema que expones en el comentario es porque en varios lenguajes, entre ellos Python, si no le das 2 valores de comparación a los condicionales (`if`, `while`), convierten tipos de datos a booleanos, y dependiendo si se evalúan `True` o `False` entrarán o no al bucle:

```py
var = "No"
if var: # <-- se convierte el valor a bool (True)
    print("Var es evaluada como True")
```

El resultado de esto es:

```
Var es evaluada como True
```

Para ver los tipos de datos que son evaluados como `True` o `False`, mirar [esta tabla](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=bool#truth-value-testing)

Para ilustrar un poco más tu código, si la persona es menor de edad, el `if` anidado solo acepta `'si'` (en minúscula) para poder responder que va acompañado por sus padres.

Si la persona es mayor de edad, se hace distinción entre `si`, `no` y cualquier otra entrada; y puede ser escrita en mayúscula o minúscula por el método [lower()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=lower#str.lower). En la última pregunta, puede escribir la respuesta de múltiples formas (si, s, yes, y), incluyendo combinaciones con mayúsculas.

```py
edad = int(input("¿Cuántos años tiene? "))
if edad < 18:
    print("Es usted menor de edad.")
    resp = input("Viene con sus padres? ")
    if resp == 'si':
        print('El menor está acompañado de sus padres')
    else:
        print('No está acompañado de sus padres o dio una respuesta no válida')
else:
    print("Es usted mayor de edad.")
    resp = input("Ud aún va a la escuela? ").lower()
    if resp == 'si':
        print('Ha respondido que aún va a la escuela')
    elif resp == 'no':
        print('Ha respondido que ya no va a la escuela')
    else:
        print('Respuesta no válida')
    # ###
    resp = input('Irá a la universidad? ')
    if resp.lower() in ['si', 's', 'yes', 'y']:
        print('La respuesta fue afirmativa')
    else:
        print('Respuesta negativa o no respondió')
```